# How do we reconcile psalms 127:3 with Ephesians 2:3?

Tags: psalms, ephesians

We read:

> Behold, children are a gift of the Lord, The fruit of the womb is a
> reward. Psalm 127:3

And:

> And you were dead in your offenses and sins, in which you previously
> walked according to the course of this world, according to the prince
> of the power of the air, of the spirit that is now working in the sons
> of disobedience. Among them **we** too all previously lived in the
> lusts of our flesh, indulging the desires of the flesh and of the
> mind, and ***were by nature children of wrath, just as the rest.***
> Ephesians 2:1-3

**Q: How are children a gift from God if we are by nature Children of wrath, just as the rest of mankind?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two references, Ps 127:3 vs Eph 2:1-3 are discussing quite different "children", and so cannot be directly compared.

- Ps 127:3 is discussing literal, biological children
- Eph 2:1-3 is discussing spiritual children in the sense of the character of all people - we are all affected by sin and so are sinful sinners.  This idea is taught in many places such as Ps 51:3-5, Rom 3:10-18, 1 John 1:8, 10, etc.

That is, Ps 127:3 is talking about the wonderful (and miraculous) gift of children to parents (a sociological fact), and Eph 2:1-3 is talking about the fact that all human beings are sinners by nature and deserve condemnation, and thus are "children of wrath".

It is precisely for this reason that Jesus taught that we need to be "born again", ie, from above, in the spiritual sense in order to be saved, John 3:3-7.  The rite of baptism symbolizes this by death the old self and resurrection to the new self.
The spiritual new birth gives us a new nature:

- 2 Cor 5:17 - Therefore if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation. The old has passed away. Behold, the new has come!
- 2 Peter 1:4 - Through these He has given us His precious and magnificent promises, so that through them you may become partakers of the divine nature, now that you have escaped the corruption in the world caused by evil desires
- 2 Cor 3:18 - And we, who with unveiled faces all reflect the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into His image with intensifying glory, which comes from the Lord, who is the Spirit.
- Rom 12:2 - Do not be conformed to this world, but be transformed by the renewing of your mind. Then you will be able to test and approve what is the good, pleasing, and perfect will of God.
- 1 Cor 2:16 - “For who has known the mind of the Lord, so as to instruct Him?” But we have the mind of Christ.